# SQLMAP - appears to be injectable, but it does not

Tags: union, sql-injection, sqlmap

[image]

Is my site vulnerable to sql injection or not?
I don't get the "UNION injectable" on all of my pages, but I get it in the user profile should  I be worried? It says 'u' is not injectable in the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQLMap is aimed for exploitation of SQL Injection, I would scan my site using other SQL Injection scanning tools (check out http://www.sectoolmarket.com/) or consult a security specialist.